# python regular expression date formate

Tags: python, regex, date

Trying to write a RE to recognize date format mm/dd in Python

```
reg = "((1[0-2])|(0?[1-9]))/((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9]))"
match = re.findall(reg, text, re.IGNORECASE)
print match
```

---

For `text = '4/13'` it gives me

```
[('4', '4', '', '13', '13', '', '', '')]
```

but not

```
'4/13'
```

Thanks,
Cheng

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are more direct, but you could also add an extra pair of braces around your regex:

`reg = "(((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9])))"`

Now `findall` will give you:

`[('4/13', '4', '4', '', '13', '13', '', '', '')]`

You can now extract `'4/13'` from above.

Comment: by the way, how do I get rid of the 4s and 13s?

Comment: You can't, using `findall` in this case. `findall` finds all patterns within pairs of braces. So you end up with the outer pattern `'4/13'` you are looking for along with some inner patterns like `'4'`, `'13'`...

Answer (score 3):

dont't use `re.findall`. use `re.match`:

```
reg = "((0?[1-9])|(1[0-2]))/((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9]))"
match = re.match(reg, text, re.IGNORECASE)
print match.group()
```