# python regular expression findall, need to remove inexact matches

Tags: python, regex

Trying to write a RE to recognize date format mm/dd in Python

```
reg = "(((1[0-2])|(0?[1-9]))/((1[0-9])|(2[0-9])|(3[0-1])|(0?[0-9])))"
match = re.findall(reg, text, re.IGNORECASE)
print match
```

---

For text = '4/13' it gives me
`[('4/13', '4', '', '4', '13', '13', '', '', '')]`

Just need the first element. I don't want inexact matches, how do I remove them.

Thanks,

Cheng

Comment: possible duplicate of [python regular expression date formate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10484300/python-regular-expression-date-formate)

Comment: @carrot-top it's same same guy asking a follow up ;-)

Comment: @cheng look at your original question, second answer with match should be a better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting all those matches because each set of parentheses in your regular expression generates a match group.  You can use a non-grouping match, such as `(?:...)`, if you really don't want the groups in your result set.  You can also simply take the first item from the list and ignore the others.

This would make your expression look like:

```
reg = "((?:(?:1[0-2])|(?:0?[1-9]))/(?:(?:1[0-9])|(?:2[0-9])|(?:3[0-1])|(?:0?[0-9])))"
```

See the `re` documentation for more information.

Here's a complete example:

```
>>> text='4/13'
>>> reg = "((?:(?:1[0-2])|(?:0?[1-9]))/(?:(?:1[0-9])|(?:2[0-9])|(?:3[0-1])|(?:0?[0-9])))"
>>> re.findall(reg, text, re.IGNORECASE)
['4/13']
```

Answer (score 0):

They're not "inexact matches". The first item in the tuple corresponds to the matched string, and the other items correspond to the sections in parentheses in your regular expression.

If there are multiple dates in the string, you want this:

```
reg = re.compile(...)
dates = [match[0] for match in reg.findall(text, re.IGNORE_CASE)]
```